# Array assignment causes segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to create a program where I can keep track of the sum of all the previous elements. Below is the code I have written. It crashes with signal 11, segmentation fault.

I tried to debug and find the cause. It turns out it works till input but when I try to assign the sum to sum array it throws the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long int n,q,l,r,i,prev=0,temp;
    long long int a[1000000], s[1000000];
    scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&q);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&temp);
        a[i]=temp;
        printf("%lld",a[i]);
        s[i]=a[i]+prev;
        prev= s[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is more likely that your arrays use too much memory, 16 MB in total. And Linux processes only gets 8 MiB of stack by default.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, You are right. I lowered the initial size and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible reason for segmentation fault in above program:

1. First Input which is for 'n' variable is greater than 1000000.

And you will get fault exception at s[I] = a[I] + prev statement while evaluating expression a[I].....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these declarations of arrays with the automatic storage duration requires much memory

```
long long int a[1000000], s[1000000];
```

Declare the arrays before the function main.

```
long long int a[1000000], s[1000000];

int main()
{
    long long int n,q,l,r,i,prev=0,temp;
    //...
```

Pay attention to that these variables `q`, `l`, and `r` are not used in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to allocate dynamically the memory for the arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    long long int n,q,l,r,i,prev=0,temp;
    long long int *a, *s;
    scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&q);
    a = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    s = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&temp);
        a[i]=temp;
        printf("%lld",a[i]);
        s[i]=a[i]+prev;
        prev= s[i];
    }
}
```